# roaming profiles + directory backup for a backup solution

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, windows-7

Right now we use acronis for our major production servers and i'm trying to find a good solution to backup our local users at little to no cost.

I'm thinking about flipping it to roaming profiles (domain accounts) and that way we can just backup the share/profiles to a local server and use rsync to back that up to a cloud server.

My major question is:

if we use roaming profiles and back it up in this fashion can you think of a way to backup a directory on the local machine? Specifically things that do not exist in that users profile (C:\appdata\applicationToBackup for example)

domain controllers are Server 2008R2 and systems are all windows 7 pro/ult.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use group policy to redirect the application data folder to a server location.

Comment: The app data directory runs a few of our programs and it has the data in it. they would still need to access it outside the corp network.

Comment: oh so this is more for mobile users to be able to function away from the network while maintaining your ability to restore their profiles if needed?

Comment: You could always just use a logoff script to copy up whatever other folders you need to the roaming profile location or other server location